# Why doesn't Masonry refresh indexes of cells (cellCount) on componentWillReceiveProps method?

Tags: react-virtualized

Every next search query starts with previous page height and index count.
What can I do to update the index count in cellRenderer and the height of the page on a new search query?
Next code help to avoid errors, but doesn't solve the problem:

```
cellRenderer = ({index, key, parent, style}) => {
    const image = this.props.images.items[index];

    if (!image) {
        console.log('!image (empty image with index: ', index, 'style', style);
        return;
    }
```

Code: [pastebin.com/FB7kzDb4](https://pastebin.com/FB7kzDb4)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

tl;dr You can fix your demo by doing the following:

```
// Clear any JIT measurements
cellMeasurerCache.clearAll();

// Reset the position cache
cellPositioner.reset({
  columnCount: this.columnCount,
  columnWidth: this.columnWidth,
  spacer: this.spacer,
});

// Let Masonry know it needs to relayout
this.masonry.clearCellPositions();
```

[Here is an example](https://github.com/bvaughn/react-virtualized/blob/cd9767a439d05d79534b70b53bbcced75dd3a81c/source/Masonry/Masonry.example.js#L279-L291) of me doing the same on the RV demo page. You can [see it running here](https://bvaughn.github.io/react-virtualized/#/components/Masonry) by clicking the "Reset List" button.

Comment: Brian, thank you for quick answer and your contribution to popularization React.js. A lot of people really appreciate it. Keep it up!